# Una más: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python

Sé que es una pregunta muy usual que suele deberse a fallos en los paréntesis, pero en este caso llevo horas intentando arreglarlo y no lo consigo.
El código sería:

```
while (len(tweet_list_ids) < tweet_query_size):
    try:
        print("Tweets %s to %s: cursor: %s" %
                (len(tweet_list_ids), len(tweet_list_ids) + 100, next_max_id))
        resul = twitter.search(q='#VolandoVoyRomanico', count = 100, max_id=next_max_id)
```

Y me da el famoso fallo

¡Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda y perdón por haberla puesto originalmente en inglés!

Comment: Alejandro, bienvenido a StackOverflow **en español**. Acá, tanto preguntas como respuestas son publicadas en la lengua de Cervantes. Por favor edita tu pregunta y dejala en español. Un saludo.

Comment: Ups, lo siento, no sé por qué pensé que estaba en el no español, tengo la cabeza loca :(
Editado ya, mil disculpas y gracias por avisar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes iniciado un bloque `try` que no se termina, por eso es que el *parser* encuentra *inesperado* el fin del archivo.

Tienes dos caminos:

- quitar la sentencia `try`

  ```
  while (len(tweet_list_ids) < tweet_query_size):
      print("Tweets %s to %s: cursor: %s" %
              (len(tweet_list_ids), len(tweet_list_ids) + 100, next_max_id))
      resul = twitter.search(q='#VolandoVoyRomanico', count = 100, max_id=next_max_id)
  ```
- completar el bloque `try` con `finally` o `except`, por ejemplo:

  ```
  while (len(tweet_list_ids) < tweet_query_size):
      try:
          print("Tweets %s to %s: cursor: %s" %
                  (len(tweet_list_ids), len(tweet_list_ids) + 100, next_max_id))
          resul = twitter.search(q='#VolandoVoyRomanico', count = 100, max_id=next_max_id)
      finally:
          print '¡eso es todo amigos!'
  ```

Comment: Perfecto, era justo lo que pasaba, muchísimas gracias amigo!!!

Comment: Un placer y un saludo. ;)